# Azure Data Factory ADF Unit Testing on feature branch without having to deploy changes to the data factory instance

Tags: nunit, specflow, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to unit test individual pipelines in Azure Data Factory on a particular branch without having to deploy my changes. Currently the only way I am able to run unit tests on ADF pipelines is by publishing my changes to the data factory instance and kick off a pipeline run. However this approach requires me to merge my changes to the collaboration branch before I am able to execute any pipeline test cases.
Ideally I'd like to be able to kick off a pipeline on particular feature branch without having to deploy to the default instance, so that I can validate my test case and make adjustments before merging it with the collaboration branch.
Any suggestions people can give or resources they can point to?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing it is not possible to command the Azure Data Factory API to run pipes in debug mode. You can call the published pipes through the REST API. If you do not want to modify the published configuration of Azure Data Factory you would need to have multiple data factories.

We use 1 ADF per engineer, and 1 ADF per higher level environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try going for Automated Unit Testing for ADF, this will enable you to write a code and the test runs before deployment.

You can check a sample for the same [here](https://richardswinbank.net/adf/set_up_automated_testing_for_azure_data_factory)

Comment: Hi @Sharingan : If my response helped you, can you please mark it as an answer so that we can have others from community to benefit from it :). Thanks !